# How to create new file to filesystem each time i add to database

Tags: java, file, prepared-statement

I have created method to add user data to database using prepared statement.I works perfectly.Now how can i create a new folder on my computer each time i add new user into database.For example when i click submit button user data is being added into database and new folder is being created in my documents folder.I tried all sorts of code it just doesn't work.I'm using Linux and Net Beans 8.1.Thanks in advance

Here is my method.

```
public String addUser(int useId, String name, String lastName, String country, String birthplace, String adress, String password) throws SQLException {
    List<User> list = listAllUsers();
    int size = list.size();



    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (useId == list.get(i).getIdUser()) {
            return "error";
        }

    }

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testBaza?user=root");
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO User (id_user,name,last_name,birthplace,country,adress,user_pass) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    ps.setInt(1, useId);
    ps.setString(2, name);
    ps.setString(3, lastName);
    ps.setString(4, country);
    ps.setString(5, birthplace);
    ps.setString(6, adress);
    ps.setString(7, password);

    ps.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();



    return "userRegPage";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work. Remember this code throws SecurityException when the uesr running the program does not have permission to create directory in the given path. So if you are running web application then run the app server with a user who have sufficient privileges.

```
public String addUser(int useId, String name, String lastName, String country, String birthplace, String adress, String password) throws SQLException {
    List<User> list = listAllUsers();
    int size = list.size();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (useId == list.get(i).getIdUser()) {
            return "error";
        }
    }

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testBaza?user=root");
    ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO User (id_user,name,last_name,birthplace,country,adress,user_pass) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    ps.setInt(1, useId);
    ps.setString(2, name);
    ps.setString(3, lastName);
    ps.setString(4, country);
    ps.setString(5, birthplace);
    ps.setString(6, adress);
    ps.setString(7, password);

    ps.executeUpdate();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();

    String folderName = "~/MyDocuments/" + id_user; // the folder name is user_id, you can use something else as well
    new File(folderName).mkdir(); // the directory is created

    return "userRegPage";
}
```

Comment: Sorry it seems not to work at least for me.I just can't figure out where my directories are being created Linux file paths are confusing to me for now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

just added this code into my method looks like i needed to add my username into file path.

```
String folderName=userId+"folder";
new File("/home/djordje/"+folderName).mkdirs();
```